# proof of undecidability of computer viruses

Tags: undecidability

I have been reading the paper of F. Cohen about viruses, here is the link:

https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~aprakash/eecs588/handouts/cohen-viruses.html

I quite not get the following part:

> ```
> Detection of Viruses
> ```
>
> > In order to determine that a given program 'P' is a virus, it must be
> >     determined that P infects other programs. This is undecidable since P
> >     could invoke the decision procedure 'D' and infect other programs if
> >     and only if D determines that P is not a virus. We conclude that a
> >     program that precisely discerns a virus from any other program by
> >     examining its appearance is infeasible. In the following modification
> >     to program V, we use the hypothetical decision procedure D which
> >     returns "true" iff its argument is a virus, to exemplify the
> >     undecidability of D.

```
program contradictory-virus:=
{...
main-program:=
 {if ~D(contradictory-virus) then
    {infect-executable;
    if trigger-pulled then do-damage;
    }
 goto next;
 }
}
```

I mean, why does P (which I believe is the program called contradictory-virus) has to decide if it is a virus or not? or in other words, why will only infect other programs if D determines that P (contradictory-virus) is not a virus? I kind of feel that this part of the proof is a little bit awkward and forced to get a contradictory result.

Any detailed explanation about this it would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how a proof-by-contradiction works? Are you familiar with Cantor's Diagonal Argument, Kurt Gödel's Proof of the Second Incompleteness Theorem, and Alan Turing's Proof of the Undecidability of the Halting Problem? This proof has a similar structure as Turing's and Gödel's, both of which are based on similar ideas as Cantor's.

Comment: I know both of them: contradiction proof and diagonal argument, but I cannot get a grasp why the program P has to evaluate itself if its a virus? I mean if its a virus then it can infect other program, but then why it only infects when P is not a virus according to D?

Comment: The virus is constructed in this particular way, because constructing it in this particular way leads to the contradiction which proves that the original assumption cannot possibly be true. This is just how a proof-by-contradiction is constructed: you assume that the thing you want to disprove is true, and then show that this leads to a non-sensical result, which means that the initial assumption must have been false. This particular trick of using a self-referential statement is the same as in Gödel's and Turing's proofs; in fact, the proof is basically an exact replica of Turing's.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this. Shouldn't decidability problems limit themselves to their input? The virus can't always test itself before infecting another program. So this would only lead to a contradiction if the decider attempted to check the virus with the virus itself as input. But there would be no contradiction if the tester checked the virus with another input.

Comment: The distinction (in my mind) being that the halting problem requires deciding for all inputs, but the virus decidability requires verifying if the virus insects *some*input. I know you can construct a virus that you can't decide this for any input, but I don't understand how this one fills the requirements.